# How to find the inverse Laplace Transforms?

Tags: laplace-transform

How do you find the inverse Laplace Transform of the following,

$$\frac{2 (s^2+4 s+5)^2+40}{(s^2+4 s+5)^2}$$

Separating them into complex coefficients is to long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F(s)$ denote the fraction in the post, hence $F(s)=2+40\frac1{(s^2+4s+5)^2}$. The $2$ part of $F(s)$ is the Laplace transform of twice the Dirac measure at $0$. The fraction $\frac1{s^2+4s+5}$ is a linear combination of $\frac1{s+2\pm\mathrm i}$ hence it is the Laplace transform of a linear combination of the functions $t\mapsto\exp(-(2\pm\mathrm i)t)$ on $t\geqslant0$, namely, the Laplace transform of $f$ where $f(t)=\mathrm e^{-2t}\sin(t)$ for every $t\geqslant0$. Thus, the fraction $\frac1{(s^2+4s+5)^2}$ is the Laplace transform of $f\ast f$, which might (or might not, check for yourself) be such that $(f\ast f)(t)=\frac12\mathrm e^{-2t}(\sin(t)-t\cos(t))$ for every $t\geqslant0$.

Finally, the function $F$ is the Laplace transform of the measure $\nu=2\delta_0+40\mu$ where $\mu$ has density $f\ast f$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $t\geqslant0$. Note that $F$ is the Laplace transform of no function, only a *measure* can do, and one has
$$
F(s)=\int_0^{+\infty}\mathrm e^{-st}\mathrm d\nu(t).
$$

Comment: Although I didn't quite get how L(f*f(t)) is equal to that, thanks for the answer :)

Comment: It is a general fact that L(f*g)=(Lf)(Lg) hence for f=g, one gets...

Comment: Are you certain?

Comment: Certain about what? (For what it is worth, as explained (and acknowledged by the OP) in the comments, the answer you accepted does not answer your question. Can you explain?)

Comment: L(f*g)=(Lf)(Lg) that this true. My book states: L(f(t)*g(t)) does not equal to L(f(t))*L(g(t)) Are you saying the accepted answer is wrong? It's like yours.

Comment: If you recognize that L(f*g)=(Lf)(Lg), I wonder what your "Are you certain?" comment was about. Can you explain? // The accepted answer is not "wrong" (did I say so? if not, why are you asking?), it is incomplete (and the OP even says so, as you know unless you did not read the answer).

Comment: I know that it is incomplete...Lets just focus on your method. What is concerning me(and thats why I asked if you are certain about it) is the statement L(f*g)=(Lf)(Lg). As  I said previously, my book states that that proposition is false. So, I am wondering why you are using it.

Comment: Why did you accept an incomplete answer then? // Re L(f*g): what is your book? On which page does it state that L(f*g) is not (Lf)(Lg)? (Say, would you be making the rather elementary mistake of taking the convolution * for the pointwise multiplication?)

Comment: You are quite condescending.(in a funny way) My course is related to electricity, so I don't actually take convolutions. I guess I did make that "elementary" mistake.

Comment: Went to study the convolution theorem and I finally get your work. So, much easier than the other work. :)

Comment: "Condescending"? You know what, one cannot expect to make people happy when one declares casually that their solution "is false". // Anyway: what is your book? (bis) On which page does it state that L(f*g) is not (Lf)(Lg)? (bis)

Comment: To be exact it is a sheet from my professor. I believe, however, that he is referring to simply multiplication instead of convolution. I want to thank you for explaining everything; it must have taken quite a load of your time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem reduces to $$2+\frac{40}{(s^2+4s+5)^2}$$

Let us denote the Laplace Transform of $f(t)$ as $L\left(f(t)\right)=F(s)$

and the inverse as $L^{-1}\left(F(s)\right)=f(t)$

For $L^{-1}\frac1{(s^2+4s+5)^2},$

$$\text{If }L\left(f(t)\right)=\frac{s-a}{\{(s-a)^2+b^2\}^2},$$

$$L\left(\frac {f(t)}t\right)=\int_s^\infty \frac{s-a}{\{(s-a)^2+b^2\}^2} ds$$
$$=\frac12\int_s^\infty \frac{2(s-a)}{\{(s-a)^2+b^2\}^2} ds=-\frac12\left(\frac1{(s-a)^2+b^2}\right)_s^\infty=\frac12\frac1{(s-a)^2+b^2}$$

$$\implies \frac {2f(t)}t=L^{-1}\left(\frac1{(s-a)^2+b^2}\right)=\frac{e^{at}\sin bt}{b} $$

$$\implies L^{-1}\frac{s-a}{\{(s-a)^2+b^2\}^2} =f(t)=\frac{te^{at}\sin bt}{2b}$$

$$a=0\implies  L^{-1}\frac s {\{s^2+b^2\}^2} =\frac{t\sin bt}{2b}$$

As  $L\{g(t)\}=G(s)\implies \int_0^tg(t)dt=L^{-1}\left(\frac{G(s)}s\right)$

$$L^{-1}\frac1{(s^2+b^2)^2}=L^{-1}\left(\frac1s\cdot \frac s{(s^2+b^2)^2}\right)=\int_0^t\frac{t\sin bt}{2b}dt=\frac{\sin bt-bt\cos bt}{2b^3}$$ (Integrating by parts)

Now using shifting property  $L\{g(t)\}=G(s)\implies L(e^{at}g(t))=G(s-a)$

So, $$L^{-1}\frac1{\{(s-a)^2+b^2\}^2}=\frac{e^{at}(\sin bt-bt\cos bt)}{2b^3}$$

Here $s^2+4s+5=(s+2)^2+1^2\implies a=-2,b=1$

Comment: Sorry but what does $L^{-1}(2)=\frac 2s$ mean?

Comment: http://www.slideshare.net/raobabu07/unit-v-laplace-transformformula  $L(1)=\frac1s$

Comment: Quite unrelated, I would say.

Comment: @Did, not sure what you mean? How do you handle the 1st part?

Comment: Sorry but this is not/should not be the question: the question is what **you** mean by $L^{-1}(2)=\frac 2s$.

Comment: @Did, sorry. Its' $L(1)=\frac1s.$ I'm not sure about the inverse.

Comment: Indeed. $ $ $ $

Answer (score 0):

I have done it, you can see if it's useful to you, I.m not sure so if you look out the mistake please fix it..

$\begin{array}{l}
 F(s) = \frac{{2{{({s^2} + 4s + 5)}^2} + 4}}{{{{({s^2} + 4s + 5)}^2}}} = 2 + \frac{{40}}{{{{{\rm{[}}{{(s + 2)}^2} + 1{\rm{]}}}^2}}} \\ 
 {L^{ - 1}}{\rm{[2]  =  }}2\delta (t) \\ 
 {\rm{\{ }}\int_0^\infty  {2.{e^{ - st}}\delta (t)dt = 2} {\rm{.}}{{\rm{e}}^{ - s0}}{\rm{ = 2\} }} \\ 
 G(s) = \frac{{40}}{{{{{\rm{[}}{{(s + 2)}^2} + 1{\rm{]}}}^2}}}{\rm{  =  40}}{\rm{.}}\frac{1}{{{\rm{[}}{{(s + 2)}^2} + 1{\rm{]}}}}.\frac{1}{{{\rm{[}}{{(s + 2)}^2} + 1{\rm{]}}}} = 40L\left[ {{e^{ - 2t}}.\sin t} \right].{L^{ - 1}}\left[ {{e^{ - 2t}}.\sin t} \right] \\ 
  =  > g(t) = {e^{ - 2t}}.\sin t*{e^{ - 2t}}.\sin t = \int_0^t {{e^{ - 2(t - u)}}.\sin (t - u).{e^{ - 2u}}.\sin u.du}  \\ 
  = {e^{ - 2t}}\int_0^t {(\sin t.\cos u - \cos t.\sin u)\sin u.du}  \\ 
  =  > g(t) = {e^{ - 2t}}\left[ {\sin t\underbrace {\int_0^t {\cos u.\sin u.du} }_{{I_1}} - \cos t\underbrace {\int_0^t {{{\sin }^2}udu} }_{{I_2}}} \right] \\ 
  =  > f(t) = 2\delta (t) + g(t) \\ 
 \end{array}$

You can evalue the integrals I1 and I2 yourself